# C++ Coin Counter Program constantly undercounts cents by .01, I don't understand why

Tags: c++, casting

I'm new to C++ and working on this lab:

> Write a program that asks the user to enter a number of quarters, dimes, nickels and pennies and then outputs the monetary value of the coins in the format of dollars and remaining cents.

The example given:

Please enter the number of coins:

- # of quarters: 20
- # of dimes: 4
- # of nickels: 13
- # of pennies: 17

The total is 6 dollars and 22 cents

Here's the code I initially used:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main() {
    
    int quarters, dimes, nickels, pennies, dollars, cents;
    double total;

    cout<<"Please enter the number of coins"<<endl;
    cout<<"# of quarters:"<<endl;
    cin>>quarters;
    cout<<"# of dimes"<<endl;
    cin>>dimes;
    cout<<"# of nickels"<<endl;
    cin>>nickels;
    cout<<"# of pennies"<<endl;
    cin>>pennies;

    total = quarters * .25 + dimes * .10 + nickels * .05 + pennies * .01;
    dollars = (int)total;
    cents = (total - dollars) * 100;

    cout<<"The total is "<<dollars<<" dollars and "<<cents<<" cents."<<endl;

    return 0;
}
```

But it kept returning 6 dollars and 21 cents. I eventually guessed and changed cents to a double and that solved it, but I'm still unsure why the first solution didn't work. I think? it has something to do with how the variables are cast, but again, that's just a guess. Any help would be great!

Comment: `double`s [are imprecise](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/588004/is-floating-point-math-broken) and should not be used for computations involving money. People get really weird when rounding doesn't go in their favour.

Comment: When I run this I get `total` of 6.2200000000000006. By the whim of the gods you could get 6.2199999999999999 which will truncate and drop a penny.

Comment: Multiply your input by 100 and work with integral pennies (cents).  Stay away from floating point.

Comment: Thanks, y'all. I changed the original to handle it all through integers and got rid of the total variable completely.

Comment: Extra reading: [Fixed Point Arithmetic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fixed-point_arithmetic).